# Shutdown doesn't work

Tags: linux, shutdown, dwm

I've installed the `dwm` window manager on Linux Mint 15, configured it and now shutdown doesn't work.

I typed `shutdown -P now` in terminal. dwm closed successfully and now I'm seeing a black screen with:

`xsetroot unabel to open display ''`

and that's all. The computer continues to operate.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think its an upper case `-P` for poweroff, check the manpage.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, my typo

Comment: Is this still a problem? Did the `-P` fix it?